# (syntax?)this.state is not a function error & sorting in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting TypeError: this.state.pageOfItems is not a function and I cant get my head around it.It's probably a syntax problem. Also I have another question: I'm trying to sort each product in its score's descending order in componentDidMount using array.sort and that also seems not to be working. Thank you so very much in advance.

```
 import React from 'react';
 import JwPagination from 'jw-react-pagination';


 class Products extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       productItems: [{
         id: '0',
         title: '1',
         price: 50,
         score: 20,
       }, {
         id: '1',
         title: '2',
         price: 30,
         score: 30,
       },
     ],
    pageOfItems:[],
  }
   this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
   this.displayProducts = this.displayProducts.bind(this);
  }

 onChangePage(pageOfItems) {
   this.setState({pageOfItems})
  }

 componentDidMount() {
   var products = this.state.productItems;
   this.setState({productItems: products.sort(function(a,b){return 
   b-a})});
 }

  displayProducts() {
   let itemList = this.state.pageOfItems(item=>{
     return(
      <div className="card" key={item.id}>
      <div className="card1">
        <span className="card-title">{item.title}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="card-content">
        <p>price: {item.price}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
   })
   return itemList;
 }

  render() {
   return(
   <div>
    <h3 className="center"> Products </h3>
    <JwPagination items={this.state.productItems} onChangePage=
    {this.onChangePage} pageSize={5}/>
    {this.displayProducts()}
  </div>
   )
  }
 }



 export default Products;
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have confused an array with the `forEach` method you find on an array.

```js
const foo = [3, 2, 1];
foo.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.state.pageOfItems` is an array. To loop through this array, do:

```
this.state.pageOfItems.map(item=> {
    return(
       <div className="card" key={item.id}>
           <div className="card1">
               <span className="card-title">{item.title}</span>
           </div>
           <div className="card-content">
               <p>price: {item.price}</p>
           </div>
      </div>
   )
})
```

You can read about Array.map here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

You should `map` or `sort` or `filter`, instead of `this.state.pageOfItems()`

```
this.state.pageOfItems.map(item=>{})
```